# shiny plotOutput(brush=...) incapable of updating mean of series of numbers and crashes

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I have a data frame with column vectors all of which I need to plot:

```
> head(data)
  nucleosome      CTCF methylation       HP1  H3K27me3   H3K9me3   H3K27ac    H3K9ac   H3K4me3   H3K4me1
1  0.5472411 0.8840290    42.42368 0.5110028 0.7020117 0.7004859 0.8756814 0.7791357 0.8077286 0.4551399
2  0.5458535 0.8760569    42.40997 0.5062004 0.7007430 0.6971006 0.8767918 0.7775829 0.8085440 0.4556197
3  0.5459417 0.8481785    42.80292 0.5022080 0.6980780 0.6957370 0.8758079 0.7786504 0.8107865 0.4556768
4  0.5467310 0.8727432    42.82729 0.5036233 0.6944849 0.7009140 0.8880359 0.7801061 0.8112621 0.4557111
5  0.5478466 0.8654194    42.64833 0.5048074 0.6956769 0.7016513 0.8878532 0.7823243 0.8130742 0.4560309
6  0.5477737 0.8324023    43.10525 0.5049416 0.6957961 0.6982977 0.8877548 0.7827680 0.8118058 0.4556540
```

The problem is that I have a bunch of artefacts in each column (incorrect spurious spikes):

[image]

I have made a shiny GUI to be able to drag my mouse over the artefacts to convert everything inside where the artefact is to the mean of the column.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click", brush = "plot_brush"),
  actionButton("button", "button")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    my <- reactiveValues(df=as.data.frame(data)) # Initialize df

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({plot(seq(-20000,20000, by=100), my$df[,which(colnames(my$df)=='HP1')], type = 'l')})

    observeEvent(input$plot_brush,{
      rowmin <- which(my$df[,1] == round(as.numeric(input$plot_brush$xmin)))
      rowmax <- which(my$df[,1] == round(as.numeric(input$plot_brush$xmax)))
      my$df[rowmin:rowmax,which(colnames(my$df)=='HP1')] <- mean(my$df[,which(colnames(my$df)=='HP1')])
    })
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      isolate(write.table(my$df,"corrected2.txt", sep='\t', quote=F))})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The problem being that the mean value of the column seems to update iteratively too quickly for shiny to handle....

I get the following error:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4022
Warning: Error in :: argument of length 0
Stack trace (innermost first):
    67: [<-.data.frame
    66: [<- [/Users/Deirdreclarkson/Downloads/test.R#19]
    65: observeEventHandler [/Users/Deirdreclarkson/Downloads/test.R#19]
     1: runApp
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problems in your approach. Despite some minor coding issues the idea works perfectly. I corrected some minor issues (especially with your `minrow` and `maxrow` and column referencing - you always referenced the first column but plotted HP1), it works like a charm on my side, but please tell me if that solves your problem? BTW thanks for the input, I didn't know about these basic plot functionalities, I would have used `plotly` for this.

```
library(shiny)

data <- read.csv(text="nucleosome,CTCF,methylation,HP1,H3K27me3,H3K9me3,H3K27ac,H3K9ac,H3K4me3,H3K4me1
                   0.5472411,0.8840290,42.42368,0.5110028,0.7020117,0.7004859,0.8756814,0.7791357,0.8077286,0.4551399
                   0.5458535,0.8760569,42.40997,0.5062004,0.7007430,0.6971006,0.8767918,0.7775829,0.8085440,0.4556197
                   0.5459417,0.8481785,42.80292,0.5022080,0.6980780,0.6957370,0.8758079,0.7786504,0.8107865,0.4556768
                   0.5467310,0.8727432,42.82729,0.5036233,0.6944849,0.7009140,0.8880359,0.7801061,0.8112621,0.4557111
                   0.5478466,0.8654194,42.64833,0.5048074,0.6956769,0.7016513,0.8878532,0.7823243,0.8130742,0.4560309
                   0.5477737,0.8324023,43.10525,0.5049416,0.6957961,0.6982977,0.8877548,0.7827680,0.8118058,0.4556540")

ui <- basicPage(
  selectInput("select", "Select column to plot and manipulate", choices=names(data)),
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click", brush = "plot_brush")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  my <- reactiveValues(df=data) # Initialize df

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({plot(my$df[, input$select], type = 'l')})

  observeEvent(input$plot_brush,{
    rowmin <- round(input$plot_brush$xmin)
    rowmax <- round(input$plot_brush$xmax)
    my$df[rowmin:rowmax, input$select] <- mean(my$df[, input$select])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]